# sqlstate "Integrity constraint violation" error when customers place an order

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, error, mysql

My customers getting the error bellow when they place an order. Orders go through, payments being taken but not inventory. Inventory stays same. Result of this customers order again. But then they are able to order without an error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '691-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I tried to repair tables, clean the cache, full index but this error comes back. This wasn't happening before. I checked catalog_product_entitiy table for entitiy_id 691 it looks normal.

This happens with two different payment method. Paypal and realex. I have checked almost everything.

magento 1.8.1 CE

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure to take the backup of the database before doing this, then run this in phpamyadmin:

```
 TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

TRUNCATE `log_customer`;
ALTER TABLE `log_customer` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_summary`;
ALTER TABLE `log_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_summary_type`;
ALTER TABLE `log_summary_type` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_url`;
ALTER TABLE `log_url` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_url_info`;
ALTER TABLE `log_url_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `report_event`;
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Hi thank you I have got this error ""Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`pf_local`.`sales_flat_quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `pf_local`.`sales_flat_quote` (`entity_i) """

Comment: set foreign_key_check = 0, before truncating, and then
set foreign_key_check = 1, not sure about the syntax

Comment: did not work... I delete and created the product that makes this problem. then I don't have any problem. It does not happen with all the products. it happens with some of them. also if the product has 1 inventory it happens. if 2 it does not happen.

Comment: Is there any extension related to product you have added?

Comment: I have xento bulk order extension and extension for realex payment method. I also have mass realted product extension...

Comment: Try disabling extension one by one, and place order , it may help debug better

Comment: nothing works. i'm completely lost and nearly crying:)